# Android emulator:no signal strength

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have built my code using the Google ICS code. The android emulator doesn't show signal strength. Is there any way to simulate a fake signal strength? Can we show a signal strength of say 3 bars at least? What changes do i have to make and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give fake values of signal strength (between 7 and 99) in `responseRilSignalStrength` function in ril.cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when emulator is running open command line and connect to it using `telnet localhost 5554` , 5554 is the port (it will be shown on top of emulator window).

After connecting run `gsm signal 2` to set signal strength to 2.

Comment: I have tried telnet.But there is no change in the signal strength.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old but still legit (in my case) and not answered.
So, after connecting to the emulator via `telnet localhost 5554` you can simulate the signal strength with

```
gsm signal-profile <strength>
```

where strength is a number between 0 and 4.